# Error while deploying Java application to Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I get the following error while deploying Java application to Weblogic server

```
weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException: 
 There are 3 nested errors:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
         Method "initialize" in class  "com.sim.try.ght.ment.cob.MentAdvancedQueueMessageListener" is 
         defined as lifecycle callback method with annotation @PostConstruct,
         but it cannot be declared to throw checked exception. 

 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.lifecyclecallback.BaseValidator.error(BaseValidator.java:206) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.lifecyclecallback.BaseValidator.error(BaseValidator.java:229) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.lifecyclecallback.BaseValidator.checkException(BaseValidator.java:178) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AbstractAnnotationValidator.checkMethod(AbstractAnnotationValidator.java:64) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AbstractAnnotationValidator.validate(AbstractAnnotationValidator.java:31) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AnnotationValidatorVisitor.visitLifeCycleCallbackBean(AnnotationValidatorVisitor.java:37) 
 at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AnnotationValidatorVisitor.visit(AnnotationValidatorVisitor.java:24) 
 at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1448) 
 at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452) 
 at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
 at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
```

> Weblogic version -12, Jdk -1,8

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: Please share the source code of the error class.

Comment: This application is already deployed on Production Weblogic. I am trying to get it run locally for myself. The application is running fine on production.